# Carlon single-outlet box with bar hanger?

Tags: electrical, rough-in

Location: US.

I need to move a baseboard outlet up to become a wall outlet (new flooring atop old flooring) and I'd like to keep the outlet centered on the wall, midway between wall studs.

Do they make a single outlet box with bar hangers, like this, only with an outlet box:
[image: light box with bar hanger]

Answer (score 2):

Just use an [old work box](https://www.google.com/search?q=old+work+box).

[image]

1. Cut the hole in the wall to fit the box.
2. Slide the box in with the tabs folded down.
3. Turn the screws until the tabs flip out and grab the back of the wallboard.

Comment: If you have to make a splice in the conductors to raise the box. you will have to leave the an opening and cover where the old connection was to maintain the splice.

Comment: I didn't know how those old work boxes were held in place.  A fact I did not include in the original question, though, is that there's an approximately 12"x16" cutout in the wall where the plaster was going to be repaired with a piece of drywall and then finished smooth. So the studs (at 16" o.c) are exposed.  That's why I was thinking of the bar hanger, since it would be easy to screw one into the studs.